# How do I import a .max file and it's associated materials and textures into Blender?

Tags: import

This model is from Mortal Kombat X and it was downloaded from the website below...

http://p3dm.ru/files/5595_tournament-reptile_.html

[image: How the model itself is supposed to look like after putting all of the files together.]

After downloading all of the files, I see lots of ones that I don't know how to work with properly. I am completely new to Blender.

I really need help with all of these files: FBX, .max,.mtl,.obj,.tga,. But I don't know how to set them up and put all of Reptile's textures on him exactly how the image displays.

Additionally, I'm also planning on taking this model and export it to Gmod and play as him.

Again, I really do need help with these files.

Comment: Upload to drive or blendswap please

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site, for a first timer I appreciate the detailed question and I can understand your frustration but I believe the marked duplicate is a sufficient answer to this issue. Blender has no native support nor will it ever for files saved in Autodesk's proprietary formats and I don't believe there are any third party solutions not including 3ds max itself. Your best bet is probably to get access to 3ds max somehow (maybe a trial), load the file and export to collada or wavefront obj.

Comment: Actually that should not be necessary, the user mentions FBX and OBJ files in the archive. My blind guess is they are all the same model with different file formats so all the user has to do is import one of the other file formats. @Cruzen7 Just import the FBX file instead, it should contain the same information as the MAX or OBJ one. TGAs are for the texture files